# How to set timeout in this socket connection and send data to client?

Tags: java, android, sockets, server, client-server

I have taken the Socket Ip and port which is entered manually, and now i want to set timeout for the socket connection. As well how to send data to the client in the below code.

```
 public void run() {
            try {
                socket = new Socket(eHostIp.getText().toString(), Integer.parseInt( eHostPort.getText().toString() ) );
                socket.connect( );
                //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                //out.println("");
                eReceiveData.setText( "Server Connected" );
                //eReceiveData.setText( socket.getInputStream().read() );

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( socket.getInputStream() ), 1024 );
                eReceiveData.setText( "Server Connected... XXXXXXX" );
                String line;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.d("read line",line);
                    eReceiveData.setText( line );
                    socket.close();
                }

                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } );
    thread.start();
```

Comment: This *is* a client. There is nothing here that is even connected to a client, let alone sends anything, anywhere. It makes exactly zero sense to close the connection inside that read loop.

Comment: i was jus trying it as the server response was received only at the time of socket close. but i want it in the field once its sent.. kindly help me in receiving the data from server once it sends. @user207421

Comment: Bit hard to debug that without seeing the server code, *nicht war?*

Answer (score 1):

Use [Socket.connect(SocketAddress endpoint, int timeout)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress,%20int)) method to specify timeout.

In order to write to a socket get output stream from it (via socket.getOutputStream()) and write to that output stream.

Note: don't close socket in your while loop! You can't write to a socket after you've closed it.